# Cut by time in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there more efficient method of grouping by time intervals than this?
Here I want to group by [00:00 - 12:00), [12:00 - 16:00), [16:00 - 00:00)

```
s = Series({
    datetime(2014, 1, 10, 0): 1,
    datetime(2014, 1, 10, 10): 2,
    datetime(2014, 1, 10, 11): 3,
    datetime(2014, 1, 12, 12): 3,
    datetime(2014, 1, 15, 17): 4,
    datetime(2014, 1, 15, 22): 5
})

arr = array([time(0), time(12), time(16)])
print s.groupby(lambda x: arr[::-1][(arr[::-1] <= x.time()).argmax()]).sum()
```

---

```
    00:00:00    6
    12:00:00    3
    16:00:00    9
    dtype: int64
```

Also, I'd like to label new index values with last datetime occuring in each group:

```
    2014-01-10 11:00:00    6
    2014-01-12 12:00:00    3
    2014-01-15 22:00:00    9
    dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Your times are not regular so a bit tricky

```
In [68]: times = ['00:00','12:00','16:00']

In [69]: Series(dict([ (start,s.between_time(start,end,include_end=False).sum()) for start,end in zip(times,times[1:]+[times[0]]) ]))
Out[69]: 
00:00    6
12:00    3
16:00    9
dtype: int64
```

On a regular grid this sums the right times

```
In [75]: x = s.resample('4H',how='sum',closed='left')

In [76]: x.groupby(x.index.time).sum()
Out[76]: 
00:00:00     1
04:00:00   NaN
08:00:00     5
12:00:00     3
16:00:00     4
20:00:00     5
dtype: float64
```